# Flutter doctor shows the message "cmdline-tools component is missing"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

when i run flutter doctor shows this
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0tYm.png)

I installed flutter and android studio in d drive. Downloaded all tools that needed.
[android studio sdk tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQq1g.png)

[android studio sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brM9r.png)

Also added the variable in both system and user.
user
[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ynv2.png)
system
[system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ3tN.png)
I cannot understand why **flutter doctor** show that error.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this, make sure you have internet connection to install the command line tools.

1. Open android studio sdk manager
2. At the SDK managers tabs, selects SDK Tools
3. From the list of tools shown, you'll see Android SDK Command-line tools.Select it and click on apply and ok.
4. Command-line tools will be installed and you are good to go.

Comment: I already downloaded Android sdk command-line tool latest version 
[click here to watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brM9r.png)
you can watch there
but still got the problem

Comment: Let me see the Error screenshot

Comment: That was the error screenshot [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0tYm.png) but i installed then in c drive and then problem was solved